# Send method as a parameter to another class

Tags: c++, c++11

I didn't really know how to search for this, so I'm going to ask the question here.
I know how to pass a function as a parameter, but this time, the situation is a bit different and I'm a bit lost.

I will simplify the classes for readability reasons, but let me know if I miss something that makes it confusing.

I have a class that calls a function inside another:

```
class Class1 : public ofBaseApp {
public:
    void setup() {
        class2.bindMethod(&Class1::thatFunction);
    }

    void thatFunction(Signature signature) {}

    Class2 class2;
}
```

Then Class2:

```
#include "js_delegate.h"
class Class2 {
public:
    void bindMethod(void (ofBaseApp::*func)(Signature signature)) {
        JSDelegate(this, func);
    } 
}
```

and the definition of JSDelegate:

```
template < class X, class Y >
FastDelegate2(Y *pthis, DesiredRetType (X::* function_to_bind)(Param1 p1) ) {
    m_Closure.bindmemfunc(detail::implicit_cast<X*>(pthis), function_to_bind); }
```

If I want to do it this way, I get an error in Class1 saying that `ofApp::*` is incompatible with `ofBaseApp::*`.

I want to make `bindMethod` generic so I can pass functions from every class that inherits from ofBaseApp. Can this be done with the current configuration, or can you suggest another way of approaching this?

Cheers

Comment: If you want to use `JSMethodHandler`, `bindMethod` etc., then this is not a C++ question but one specific to the library of JSMethodHandler. This can be handled with C++ standard library tools since C++11, like @moooeeeep mentioned, but it looks like you want to specific use the functions, mentioned in your code?!

Comment: Is it mandatory to enforce that passed function is method of child of ofBaseApp?

Comment: is there a reason you don't just use `std::function`?

Comment: @Superlokkus let's forget about JSMethodHandler then, and concentrate on the `FasDelegate` template. I'm a bit confused about this part: `X::*function_to_bind`. I want to be able to pass `AnyClass::function` to `bindMethod`, but I don't know how to write the definition of `bindMethod` to enable me to do that

Comment: @Slava not necessarily, but I don't know how to write the `bindMethod` definition to allow me to pass methods from any class

Comment: As far as I understand from your comments to your question you want to 
**declare a function that takes any method and instance from a specific class or their derived classes**?

Comment: @Superlokkus: don't shout. plain quotes or some other notation will do the trick.

Comment: @Superlokkus yup, that's what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

So according to the comments:

```
template <class class_type,class function_type>
void bind_base_method(function_type function, base& instance) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<base,class_type>::value || std::is_same<base,class_type>::value, "class_type is not derived of base or base");
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<function_type>::value, "Function is not a member function");
}
```

should work for you as needed.
For how to use [see here](https://ideone.com/biQ3EI) or use the example code below:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream> //just form cout for demonstration

class base {
    int number = 42;
public:
    void a_method(void) {
        std::cout << number << std::endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base {

};

class another_class{
public:
    void a_method(void) {
        std::cout << 41;
    }
};

template <class class_type,class function_type>
void bind_base_method(function_type function, base& instance) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<base,class_type>::value || std::is_same<base,class_type>::value, "class_type is not derived of base or base");
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<function_type>::value, "Function is not a member function");

    //call like
    auto this_will_call_the_method = std::bind(function, instance);

    this_will_call_the_method();
}

int main(void)
{
    derived foo;
    bind_base_method<derived>(&derived::a_method, foo);

    another_class bar;
    //bind_base_method(&another_class::a_method, bar);//error won't work as wanted

    return 0;
}
```